# Boost bind inside Boost packaged_task. Why boost asio thinks its not CompletionHandler?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread, boost-bind

So all my work happens inside of a class named `thread_pool`. This code will work no matter what run_item takes into itself:

```
template <class task_return_t>
    void thread_pool::pool_item( boost::shared_ptr< boost::packaged_task<task_return_t> > pt)
    {
        internal_tasks.post(boost::bind(&thread_pool::run_item<task_return_t>, this, pt));
//...
```

This will not compile:

```
template <class task_return_t>
    void thread_pool::pool_item( boost::shared_ptr< boost::packaged_task<task_return_t> > pt)
    {
         boost::packaged_task<void> task ( boost::bind(&thread_pool::run_item<task_return_t>, this, pt)));
        internal_tasks.post( task);
```

Why? And how to make it compile?

I use boost 1.47.0. Errors my VS2010 talls me:

```
Error   6   error C2665: 'boost::asio::detail::zero_arg_handler_test' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types    C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost-1.47.0\include\boost\asio\impl\io_service.hpp  88  1   cf-server

Error   9   error C2664: 'void boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::post<CompletionHandler>(Handler)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::packaged_task<R>' to 'boost::packaged_task<R>'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost-1.47.0\include\boost\asio\impl\io_service.hpp  90  1   cf-server

Error   8   error C2664: 'T &boost::asio::detail::lvref<CompletionHandler>(T)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::packaged_task<R>' to 'boost::packaged_task<R>'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost-1.47.0\include\boost\asio\impl\io_service.hpp  88  1   cf-server

Error   7   error C2664: 'boost::asio::detail::clvref' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::packaged_task<R>' to 'boost::packaged_task<R>'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Boost-1.47.0\include\boost\asio\impl\io_service.hpp  88  1   cf-server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the function `thread_pool::run_item<task_return_t>` accepts a non-const packaged task reference (or pointer) but boost::bind made a `const` copy, and is unable to pass the argument.

Without seeing the `run_item` signature, I can't tell exactly, but that's where I would look.

Edit:  Looking a bit deeper (once I could get to a copy of boost 1_47), the problem is that `boost::packaged_tasks` are not copyable, however, `boost::asio::io_service` requires that CompletionHandler be CopyConstructable.  Since `boost::packaged_tasks` are only MoveConstructable/MoveAssignable, you cannot pass them directly to the io_service.

See [Boost.Asio requirements for CompletionHandlers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html)

Comment: yep - [fixed it in my threads_pool\task_manager](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudServer/src/cf-util/thread_pool.h?spec=svn1478&r=1478)  I create a bufer function that just executes task via `task()`